# C++ Syntax for accessing operator () from a pointer to an object

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an instance of the C++ 11 random number distribution; `uniform_int_distribution`, and an instance of the C++ `m19937_64` algorithm.

I am passing references to these using pointers to a class which maintains a pointer to these 2 objects for later use.

In a member function of this class, I wish to call the `operator()` function to generate a random number from the `uniform_int_distribution`.

I have done the following. (May be incorrect, hence the question.)

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
std::mt19937_64 *gen_p = &gen;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 9);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> *dis_p = &dis;
```

Then I do the following: (Later in code, within my class member function.)

```
int random_number = (*dis_p)(*gen_p);
```

This looks a bit strange or ambiguous, or at least it does to me since I've not encountered this before.

Without pointers, one would do the following:

```
int random_number = dis(gen_p);
```

Comment: You could use `->`, but frankly, why not store the created values? Why do you use pointers at all?

Comment: This looks perfectly fine: putting parentheses around the dereference expression `*dis_p` makes it do exactly what you want. However, unless there is a possibility that `dis_p` needs to be `NULL` under some circumstances, you could replace a pointer with a reference, and get your familiar syntax back.

Comment: I think you should just get used to this syntax which is common in C++ (and C) code involving pointers. Otherwise, yes, move away from them and you'll never have to digest such arcane syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
(*dis_p)(*gen_p);
```

(as you are) or

```
dis_p->operator()(*gen_p);
```

Personally, however, I would not use pointers at all.  Instead

```
dis(gen);
```

will do the trick  (since `dis_p` points at `dis` and `gen_p` points at `gen`).

It is possible to store references in a class (albeit they need to be initialised using a constructor, and cannot be reseated like pointers can).

Answer (score 0):

you can also convert the pointers into references first:

```
auto& rDis = *dis_p;
auto& rGen = *gen_p;
rDis(rGen);
```

the compiler will optimize the whole deal to become `(*dis_p)(*gen_p)` anyway, so no run-time overhead.

Also, there is nothing wrong with plain `(*dis_p)(*gen_p)`, I don't think it's that confusing.